# Driving MOSFET with the PWM output of TL494

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

[image][image]As per the given circuit diagram , I am trying to drive the mosfet but the issue   i am facing is that when m connecting mosfet with the PWM output of TL494 ..m getting a high rise time in the pulse...how to decrease the rise time of the pulse. Figure 1 shows the plot when mosfet is not connected. Figure 2 when mosfet is connected.[image]

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to show how the FET is connected.  Are pins 9 and 10 really unconnected?.  I suspect you're going to need a gate driver.

Comment: Use something like a UC3842 which is designed to drive a mosfet.

Comment: Is the mosfet gate being driven through the 1k resistors?

Comment: pins 9 and 10 are grounded.

Comment: Yes the MOSFET is being driven through the 1K ohm resistor ...

Comment: Except UC3842,  what other ways are there for gate driver. Could u suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use discrete gate driver that consists from two transistors. I simulated it in LTSpice. The turn-of time (with given resistors) is roughly 300 nano Seconds. Turn-on time is roughly 100 nSec. It (turn on/off time) depends on the gate charge and you can increase charge/discharge time when you change R4, R1. Te resistor R4 connected  to IC (to pin 11 or 9). The schema is here:
[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmT6kE14U6MwbNzWVo_jFp03Ntweo8OY/view?usp=sharing]

The power supply source (V2) for gate must have low internal resistance and parallel capacitor 100-220n between rails to forcing switching speed of the mosfet .

Comment: Hi there! Can you fill in a couple of bits for me, like that **R4 is connected to IC** (TL494?), when your answer is about using discrete components. Thank you.